# python ,scipy -- how to return a value with probability between 2 values

Tags: python, scipy

I have sth like this:

```
empty=0
full=1
burn=2
myprob=0.7

if cell==burn:
   return (empty or full) with probability  myprob
```

How can i do it?
Thanks!

Comment: Look at http://docs.python.org/library/random and see if you can work something out.

Comment: I mean this in the nicest possible way, but you might imagine that after asking *87* questions here, you would have begun to understand a bit about both what constitutes a good question on stackoverflow and how to express a question so that those answering can easily understand what it is you are asking and give you a relevant answer. I would ask you to read this comment through and then immediately re-read your question, and then maybe think about how you could edit it so that someone else could get even the faintest idea what you are asking about.

Comment: @talonmies:I try to write as good as i can.But that is not always possible (for a number of reasons).But,some seem to understand what i want to ask.I think i was "clear" . return "(empty or full) with probability  myprob" .Maybe you misunderstood because i had it inside the code?Of course after your comments i will try to do better!No hard feelings and please always correct me about my questions,my code etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The expression

```
numpy.random.random() < myprob
```

will evaluate to `True` with probability `myprob`.  Since `False` and `True` interpreted as integers are `0` and `1`, you can use

```
[empty, full][numpy.random.random() < myprob]
```

to select between the two given values with the given probability.  For your particular values of `empty` and `full`, the first expression will basically do the same -- you only need the second one if `empty` and `full` aren't `0` and `1` respectively.

Comment: An equivalent expression is `full if numpy.random.random() < myprob else empty`, which to me looks a little more elegant, though you might disagree.  Note that this evaluates to `full` with probability `myprob` - I'm not sure it is clear if that's what you wanted.

Comment: @James:Thanks.I want to select between empty and full with the given probability.

Comment: @George: sorry, the point I was trying to make is that you didn't distinguish whether you wanted `full` with probability `myprob` and `empty` with probability `1-myprob`, or else `empty` with probability `myprob` and `full` with probability `1-myprob` - in other words, whether you want to return `empty` 70% of the time or 30% of the time.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure I understand your question. In your code:

```
return (empty or full) with probability  myprob

(empty or full) #will always be 1
```

So I'm gonna assume what you want is something:

0.7 = 70% of the times return empty
0.3 = 30% of the times return full

If this is what you want, all you need to do is:

```
   from random import random
   if cell==burn:
       return (random() > my_prob)
```

`random()` will return a number between 0->1. if you have different value from 0/1 as `empty` and `full` just do an extra `if` condition.

Comment: :Thanks for your answer.I chose the other because it had the expression [empty, full][numpy.random.random() < myprob] ,which i liked more.I voted up though,thanks again.